# How to change text color of actionSheet in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to change color of actionSheet's text in SwiftUI. Unable to do so. I tried following code

```
    private var actionSheet: ActionSheet {
    let button1 = ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Week 1").foregroundColor(.orange)) {
        self.selectedShuffleWeek = "Week 1"
        self.shufflePresented = true
        self.actionSheetPresented = false
    }
    let button2 = ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Week 2").foregroundColor(Color("GreenColor"))) {
        self.selectedShuffleWeek = "Week 2"
        self.shufflePresented = true
        self.actionSheetPresented = false
    }
    let button3 = ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Week 3").foregroundColor(Color("GreenColor"))) {
        self.selectedShuffleWeek = "Week 3"
        self.shufflePresented = true
        self.actionSheetPresented = false
    }
    let dismissButton = ActionSheet.Button.cancel {
        self.selectedShuffleWeek = ""
        self.actionSheetPresented = false
    }


    let buttons = [button1, button2, button3, dismissButton]
    return ActionSheet(title: Text("Shuffle"),
                       buttons: buttons)
}
```

After that I also tried to change the accent color of the view in which I am showing this action sheet but its not working.

Comment: Is "GreenColor" a custom color?

Comment: Yes this was from assets

Comment: Have you been able to accomplish this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 14):

I've managed to get this working by adding the following code in `SceneDelegate` inside `func scene(_...`

```
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = Color("GreenColor")
```

This will change the accent colour of all ActionSheets in your application.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated for iOS 14**

Based on Gian's answer.

Step 1. Go to **Assets.xcassets** and in Colors folder add your custom color with a name **myCustomColor**

Step 2. You need to write an extension to Color. I add such things in **DesignSystem.swift** I create for all the custom fonts and colors I am using.

```
extension Color {
    public static let myCustomColor = Color("myCustomColor")
}
```

Step 3. Add the following code in **SceneDelegate** inside **func scene(_...**

```
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = UIColor(Color.myCustomColor)
```