# how to change actionsheet default button color in swiftui and how to set different color for selected button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: $showLocationOptions) {
    ActionSheet(title: Text("Which city/town is this place in ?"), message: Text("Select a location"), buttons: [

    .default(Text(location1)) {  },
    .default(Text(location2)) {  },
    .default(Text(location3)) {  },
    .default(Text(location4)) {  },
    .default(Text(location5)) {  },
    .destructive(Text("Cancel")){      
        }    
    ])
}
```

Comment: no you can't. you can only change all Alert button colors in your App: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347423/how-to-change-text-color-of-actionsheet-in-swiftui

Comment: Give me any suggestions.. how will users know which button is selected currently.

Comment: The `.actionSheet` just offers different actions. You might want a `Picker` in a  `.sheet` which shows the active selection and lets you pick another